# Counter example of rellich-kondrachov compact embedding theorem on unbounded domain

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The Rellich-Kondrachov Compactness Theorem says that when $U$ is a bounded set with $C^1$ boundary then $W^{1,p}(U)$ is compactly embedded into $L^{q}(U)$ for every $1 \leq q < p^{*}$.

What if $U$ is unbounded, e.g. $U=\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a bump function $ f $ with compact support.  Define $ f_n $ to be a translation of $f$ in some direction, say along the first coordinate axis.  These clearly don't have a limit in $ L^q $.

Answer (score 10):

As Jake pointed out, the embedding fails in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ because we can find a sequence of bumps bounded in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ that go to infinity.

However, it turns out that there **are**  unbounded domains $U$ with $W^{1,p}(U)\subset \subset L^{p}(\Omega)$ - you can find some of them in the book *Sobolev Spaces* by *Adams*.

In the more specific case of $W^{1,p}_{0}(U)$ for example, there are a few nice geometric conditions we can impose on unbounded $U$ so that the embedding is compact.

A necessary one is the following: $U$ must not contain infinitely many disjoint $\epsilon$-balls - otherwise, choose a sequence of bumps in those balls and apply the same argument as in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to contradict compactness.

Actually, in $n=1$ dimension, this is even sufficient and there is a nice elementary proof using only the fundamental theorem of calculus.

In higher dimensions, we need $U$ to be "sufficiently thin as we approach infinity" - what exactly that means you can read about in the book mentioned above.